# Axios-Redux in React to an Express endpoint-both .then and .catch triggered

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, axios

I'm using a Redux Form to send a POST call to an Express endpoint. The endpoint is supposed to return the successfully saved object, or an error.

The endpoint successfully saves the posted data and returns the JSON. But Axios in the Redux action picks up both the .then and the .catch triggers-in the following action, it logs the following:

```
successful response:  { …}
failure response:  undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

My Axios action:

```
export function addPlot(props) {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    return function(dispatch) {
        axios
            .post(
                `${ROOT_URL}/plots`,
                {
                    props
                },
                { headers: { authorization: user.token } }
            )
            .then(response => {
                console.log('successful response: ', response.data);
                const plotModal = document.getElementById('plotModal');
                plotModal.modal('dispose');
                dispatch({ type: PLOT_ADDED, payload: response.data });
                dispatch({ type: ADDING_PLOT, payload: false });
                dispatch({
                    type: NEW_PLOT_GEOJSON,
                    payload: ''
                });
            })
            .catch(response => {
                console.log('failure response: ', response.data);
                dispatch(authError(PLOT_ADD_FAILURE, 'Failed to add plot'));
            });
    }
```

My endpoint:

```
exports.newPlot = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.props));
    let company;
    if (req.user.companyCode !== 'Trellis') {
        company = req.user.companyCode;
    } else {
        company = req.body.props.company;
    }
    const {
        name,
        feature,
        growerPhone,
        plotCode,
        rootStock,
        region,
        variety,
        grower,
        planted
    } = req.body.props;
    const plot = new Plot({
        name,
        grower,
        variety,
        planted,
        region,
        rootStock,
        plotCode,
        growerPhone,
        feature,
        company
    });
    try {
        const newPlot = await plot.save();
        res.json(newPlot);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("couldn't save new plot", JSON.stringify(e));
        return res.status(422).send({ error: { message: e, resend: true } });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `redux-thunk` middleware to manage async actions.

The problem I see is that you are not dispatching the axios action, you must call `dispatch(this.props.addPlot(props))`in order to do something in the redux store.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: You weren't dispatching the action (or thunk) `addPlot`. At the moment of tha call, in your react component, you must wrap it with `this.props.dispatch`. Hope it works.